# ProxySQL: how to configure a failover?

Tags: mariadb, proxysql

How can I config ProxySQL to have a failover, independent from read-only or not. The parameter 'weight' in mysql_servers do not work properly in this case. I have some nodes (MariaDB 10.3) with master-master-replication, and If node1 goes offline, node2 should perform the statements. If node1 is back, it should be the first server again.
With my setup (all 3 servers in one hostgroup, only with different 'weight') the failover works, but with up to 9 seconds delay for the first statements after failover, and if node1 is back, the first server remains on node2.
How can I configure a failover with a fixed priorisation the best way? Should it be done in the hostgroup or in the rules? Or maybe it's not possible with ProxySQL?

PS: Maybe a similar question: [ProxySQL active-standby setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58080480/proxysql-active-standby-setup)